# Wildfly systemd service randomly exits

Tags: wildfly, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

I have Ubuntu 18.04 server and Wildfly 18.0.1. Wildfly installed as system service and it works normally - I can start, stop it. It starts on system boot.

But sometimes this service randomly stops with no reason - one time per week, one time per couple of days. I didn't see any dependency on server load.

In logs there is just:

```
Mar 18 15:28:27 prdmx systemd[1]: wildfly.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 18 15:28:27 prdmx systemd[1]: wildfly.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

wildfly.service is original file with no change:

```
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
User=wildfly
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/var/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There is absolutely nothing in system logs, nothing in wildfly logs, except two lines I mention above.
So I even don't know is it wildfly problem or systemd problem.

What can I do with it? How to get the source of this behaviour - systemd or wildfly? How to debug it all?

(I can set "restart on failure" option for service but it's not good solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Wildfly issue. More precisely Java app issue. One of the apps take huge amount of memory, and when it become 100% RAM and 100% swap then Ubuntu kernel simply kills this service with no error.